# Is there any way to send and recive messages using one connection with socket in Kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin, sockets

From what I know already, one socket should handle multiple clients (connections) and one client (connection) should handle send and recive(listen) actions. I can achive this by running a few clients in CLI on the golang server.

```js
package main

import (
    "bufio"
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "net"
)

var clients = make(map[string]net.Conn) //Connected 
var registredClients = make(map[int]net.Conn) //Recognized by id
var messages = make(chan message)

type message struct {
    text        string
    address     string
    RecipientID int
    senderId    int
}

type comunicateJson struct {
    Mode        int    `json:"mode"`
    SenderID    int    `json:"senderId"`
    RecipientID int    `json:"recipientId"`
    Message     string `json:"message"`
    Param1      int    `json:"param1"`
    Param2      int    `json:"param2"`
}

type uRegisterJson struct {
    ClientId int `json:"clientId"`
}

func main() {

    listen, err := net.Listen("tcp", "XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX:9999")

    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    go broadcaster()

    for {
        conn, err := listen.Accept()
        if err != nil {
            log.Print(err)
            continue
        }
        go handle(conn)
    }

}
func handle(conn net.Conn) {
    clients[conn.RemoteAddr().String()] = conn

    fmt.Println("CONNECT " + conn.RemoteAddr().String())
    

    input := bufio.NewScanner(conn)
    for input.Scan() {

        fmt.Println("Scan " + conn.RemoteAddr().String())
        fmt.Println(input.Text())
        messages <- newMessage(input.Text(), conn)
    }
    

    //Delete client form map
    rmUser(conn)
    delete(clients, conn.RemoteAddr().String())
    conn.Close() // NOTE: ignoring network errors
}

func isJSON(s string) bool {
    var js map[string]interface{}
    return json.Unmarshal([]byte(s), &js) == nil
}

func rmUser(con net.Conn) {
    for i, s := range registredClients {
        if s == con {
            delete(registredClients, i)
        }
    }
}

func newMessage(msg string, conn net.Conn) message {
    fmt.Println("Proccces message")
    fmt.Println(msg)
    if isJSON(msg) {
        res := comunicateJson{}
        json.Unmarshal([]byte(msg), &res)

        res2 := uRegisterJson{}
        json.Unmarshal([]byte(msg), &res2)

        if res.RecipientID != 0 && res.SenderID != 0 { //NOTE: parssing individual message

            addr := conn.RemoteAddr().String()
            senderId := res.SenderID
            reciverId := res.RecipientID

            
            fmt.Printf("Message from clientId %d to clientId %d\n", res.SenderID, res.RecipientID)
            return message{
                text:        msg,
                address:     addr,
                senderId:    senderId,
                RecipientID: reciverId,
            }


        } else if res2.ClientId != 0 { //NOTE: client register

            fmt.Printf("New clientId %d\n", res2.ClientId)
            registredClients[res2.ClientId] = conn
        }

    }

    addr := conn.RemoteAddr().String()

    return message{
        text:    msg,
        address: addr,
    }

}

func broadcaster() {
    for {
        select {
        case msg := <-messages:
            /*
                for i, v := range registredClients {
                    if msg.RecipientID == i {
                        fmt.Fprintln(v, msg.text)
                    }

                }
            */
            for _, conn := range clients {
                if msg.address == conn.RemoteAddr().String() { //NOTE: ignoring sender
                    continue
                }
                fmt.Fprintln(conn, msg.text)
            }

        }
    }
}
```

The interesting part is the commented loop in the broadcaster. Every client who shares his ID (json) can became a registredClient. If the messages recipientId matches the clients id the message is send to that specific client.

My problem is that I cannot build such client in Kotlin. The only way I can send a message is by setting socket.close() and my server has no reason to register such a client. For obvious reasons, I do not want to send a message to every connected clinet.

For sending messages to socket I'am using a kotlin service executed in Fragment/Activity

```js
class SendMessageService: Service() {



    override fun onStartCommand(intent: Intent?, flags: Int, startId: Int): Int {
        var messageType = intent?.getStringExtra("messageType")
        when(messageType) {
            "m1" -> messageOne(startId)
            "m2" -> messageTwo(startId)
        }
        return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
    }



    private fun messageOne(startId: Int) {
        val jsonObj = JSONObject()
        jsonObj.put("mode",1)
        jsonObj.put("senderId",getUserId())
        jsonObj.put("recipientId",100)
        jsonObj.put("message","messageOne")
        jsonObj.put("param1",1)
        jsonObj.put("param2",2)


        CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO).launch() {
            val socket = Socket(GlobalVars().socketHost, GlobalVars().socketPort)
            socket.outputStream.write(jsonObj.toString().toByteArray())
            socket.close()
        }
        stopSelf(startId)
    }



    private fun messageTwo(startId: Int) {
        val jsonObj = JSONObject()
        jsonObj.put("mode",1)
        jsonObj.put("senderId",getUserId())
        jsonObj.put("recipientId",100)
        jsonObj.put("message","messageTwo")
        jsonObj.put("param1",1)
        jsonObj.put("param2",2)
        CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO).launch() {
            val socket = Socket(GlobalVars().socketHost, GlobalVars().socketPort)
            socket.outputStream.write(jsonObj.toString().toByteArray())
            socket.close()
        }
        stopSelf(startId)
    }


    ...
}
```

I don't realy care about the socket.close() here, as long as the message contains the receiverId, the server should know where to deliver it.

For reciving messages from socket am using a Kotlin CoroutineWorker witch is executed in anather Worker.

```js
class SocketWorker(
    context: Context,
    workerParams: WorkerParameters
) : CoroutineWorker(context, workerParams) {
    var notifyid : Int = 0

    override suspend fun doWork(): Result = withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {

        val jsonObj = JSONObject()
        jsonObj.put("clientId",getUserId())

        try {
            var socket = Socket(GlobalVars().socketHost, GlobalVars().socketPort)
            PrintWriter(socket.outputStream, true).write(jsonObj.toString()) //This line does not do anything.
            //socket.close()
            var text = ""
            while (true) {
                text = BufferedReader(InputStreamReader(socket.inputStream)).readLine()
                if (text.contains("recipientId")){
                    val gson = Gson()
                    val socketObj: SocketMassage = gson.fromJson(text, SocketMassage::class.java)
                    if (socketObj.recipientId == getUserId()) { //Socket should be sending to one Client
                        generateNotification("Title", "Worker")
                    }
                }
            }

            Result.failure()



        } catch (ex: IOException) {
            Log.e("felixb", "Socket Error Worker Down")
            Result.failure()
        }

    }

    ...
}
```

I am trying here to send a clients id that can be captured by the server and turn the socket thing to listening for new messages. If I close the socket the server will remove the client from the registredClients and there will be no message for that specific client provided by the servers brodcaster commented loop.

Is there any way to send and recive messages using one connection with socket in Kotlin?

**Ktor runBlocking** new aproach

```js
class SocketWorker(appContext: Context, workerParams: WorkerParameters): Worker(appContext, workerParams) {

    var notifyid : Int = 0


    @WorkerThread
    override fun doWork(): Result {
        Log.e("felixb","WORK BEFORE runBlocking")
        return runBlocking {
            Log.e("felixb","WORK in runBlocking")
            val jsonObj = JSONObject()
            jsonObj.put("clientId",getUserId())
            val selectorManager = SelectorManager(Dispatchers.IO)
            val socket = aSocket(selectorManager).tcp().connect(GlobalVars().socketHost, GlobalVars().socketPort)

            val receiveChannel = socket.openReadChannel()
            val sendChannel = socket.openWriteChannel(autoFlush = true)

            launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
                while (true) {
                    val incomingMessage =  receiveChannel.readUTF8Line()
                    if (incomingMessage != null) {
                        Log.e("felixb",incomingMessage)
                    } else {

                        Log.e("felixb","Server closed a connection")
                        socket.close()
                        selectorManager.close()
                        exitProcess(0)
                    }
                }
            }

            while (true) {
                Log.e("felixb","Send message ")
                val greeting = jsonObj.toString()
                sendChannel.writeStringUtf8(greeting)
            }

            Result.failure()
        }
    }

    ...


}
```

I've change the doWork body for anather aproach exchanging messages with socket using ktor and runBlocking. The things got creazy in ktor. I've got multiple connection around hundred (server log) and each of them is immidietly closed and after that there are caming multiple messages sended (client log) and never reach the server couz is no connection. Seems the ktor is trying to send a message with no connection. I belive that my ktor client is not compatible with the go server.

[android log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dWfKY.png)

In the android log the red text is from messageOne and the white is from messageTwo i think that is a proof that the methods ware executed.

[server log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y01ZO.png)

In the server log there are two consoles the lef one is showing what is going on in the server and the right one is the for the go client reciving all messages captured by the server while for now the server is sendig them to every connected client.

The blue arrow shows the go client
The red arrow shows the messageOne android client
The green arrow shows the messagaTwo android client

Comment: There is a server socket and a client socket. A server socket can handle multiple clients and every client can exchange as much messages with the server as its wants. No need to close sockets to send or receive messages. I dont understand your problem or what you ask.

Comment: My android app won't send messages without closing the socket. In other words, the app will not send a message if the socket.close() is not set. In cli the job is done. I can send multiple messages until i decide to disconect. The question is how to achive that in android with Kotlin

Comment: Is your Android app a server or a client? Is the message not send or not received if you dont close the socket? Closing client socket or server socket? You see you should be much more to the point.

Comment: Android is a Client and the Server is written in go tested with go Clients. An Android client can send a message to the server witch is present there after the connection is closed by the clinet. I cannot hold a connection wihle sending and reciving. BTW in the go socket server documentation I read that every conection has to be closed from the server after is established, it seems very strange to me. My server does not do it.

Comment: You do it wrong if you have to close the client socket to let the receiver get the message. Show both client sending code and receiver receiving code. There is no need for closing. Never.

Comment: They tread the socket like API GATEWAY but I want to use it for notifications becaouse I'm not satisfied by the google firebase messaging service. As I tested it with go client in the command line, everything was fine. The message appeared in the server and then depends on what I want to do I could send it to all clients or to one client. The weird thing with the message not present in server starts in android witch is finaly present when i close the connection by the client.

Comment: Yes you coded it wrong.

Comment: The Kotlin CoroutineWorker is the main problem I cannot PrintWriter(socket.outputStream, true).write(jsonObj.toString()) without closing the connection but when I'm reading from server text = BufferedReader(InputStreamReader(socket.inputStream)).readLine() without passing the clientId in that specific connecion I'm not able to make the server send a message to that specific clinent I can only send messages to all clients and recive it here.

Comment: All makes no sense to me. And now you described two problems. A client that has to close the socket. And a server that cannot send to a specific client. Concentrate on one problem first please.

Comment: The problem is one. The server is able to tag the connection with a clientId when the clinet send it. Unfortynly when am using  var socket = Socket(GlobalVars().socketHost, GlobalVars().socketPort) i can either listen to server or send a message by flushing and closing the connnecton.

Comment: There is no reason why you would be restricted to that. But as you are not going into the probelm itself the whole time then what do you expect?

Comment: I don't want a server that sends every received message to all connected clients. To achive that I need one simple singleton send/recive client connection. Am suprised that the base Kotlin Socket class can send a message only if i close the socket. Perhaps Ktor is waiting for a a specific respond from a server otherwise the connection is closed by the clinet.

Comment: I did not ask for that information now. Please concentrate on the closing problem. Tell why you have to close the client.

Comment: If I don't set the clients socket.close() the message will never reach the server and it confuses me. It seams to be one shoot comunication.

Comment: methods messageOne() and messageTwo() have a socket.close() and the message is recived by the server but when i remove the socket.close() the mesage is not present in the server

Comment: My god.. you should tell what goes wrong when the client does not close. What happens instead? Which statement fails? Give us info as you are only repeating yourself without coming to the point.

Comment: The socket.close() statment is problematic when I want to send/recive in one connection. I'm not able to freez the socket client in listening when closing the connection and I can't send a message to a socket server if i don't close the connection. The statement PrintWriter(socket.outputStream, true).write(jsonObj.toString()) is waiting for the socket.close() to send a mesage.

Comment: No. I do not believe that. The message will be sent (well if you flush()). I recon the message is not received . So you should tell which statement at the receiver side does not receive until the client is closed.

Comment: The input.Scan() loop on the server side.  I don't belive that the reciver fails. I will remove the socket.close() in messageOne() and post everything I will find usefull.

Comment: How does jsonObj.toString() look like? Does it contain newline characters?

Comment: The jsonObject is created inside both methods. Visible in the android logs. The mesageTwo string is also visible in the server log, it is one line string with no newline characters.

Comment: Please note that the "after socket.outputSteam" log apears after the "messageTwo end" and "messageOne end" what could mean that it has something to do with the stopSelf(startId)

Comment: Then add a newline: socket.outputStream.write((jsonObj.toString()+"\n").toByteArray()) And add a flush().

Comment: I couldn't add a flush but the newline character helps. The messageOne was succesfuly delivered to the server the connection remains open. I believe I can handle the recive/send in one connection now. Is there any way that I can show that you ware very helpfull?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a newline:

```
socket.outputStream.write((jsonObj.toString()+"\n").toByteArray())
```

And add a flush().